# Transaction simulation failed: This program may not be used for executing instructions

Tags: rust, smartcontracts, solana

I've been working through the hello world for Solana but I'm trying to get the smart contract written in Rust to be executed using the `solana` Python module in order to truly understand how the process goes. I've managed to deploy the following smart contract onto the `localhost` test validator:

```rust
use borsh::{BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize};
use solana_program::{
    account_info::{next_account_info, AccountInfo},
    entrypoint,
    entrypoint::ProgramResult,
    msg,
    program_error::ProgramError,
    pubkey::Pubkey,
};

/// Define the type of state stored in accounts
#[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, Debug)]
pub struct GreetingAccount {
    /// number of greetings
    pub counter: u32,
}

// Declare and export the program's entrypoint
entrypoint!(process_instruction);

// Program entrypoint's implementation
pub fn process_instruction(
    program_id: &Pubkey, // Public key of the account the hello world program was loaded into
    accounts: &[AccountInfo], // The account to say hello to
    _instruction_data: &[u8], // Ignored, all helloworld instructions are hellos
) -> ProgramResult {
    msg!("Hello World Rust program entrypoint");

    // Iterating accounts is safer than indexing
    let accounts_iter = &mut accounts.iter();

    // Get the account to say hello to
    let account = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;

    // The account must be owned by the program in order to modify its data
    if account.owner != program_id {
        msg!("Greeted account does not have the correct program id");
        return Err(ProgramError::IncorrectProgramId);
    }

    // Increment and store the number of times the account has been greeted
    let mut greeting_account = GreetingAccount::try_from_slice(&account.data.borrow())?;
    greeting_account.counter += 1;
    greeting_account.serialize(&mut &mut account.data.borrow_mut()[..])?;

    msg!("Greeted {} time(s)!", greeting_account.counter);

    Ok(())
}
```

This is deployed fine and I've managed to create accounts and transact a token with the Python code below:

```py
from solana.keypair import Keypair
from solana.publickey import PublicKey
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solana.system_program import TransferParams, transfer
from solana.transaction import Transaction
import time

cli = Client('http://127.0.0.1:8899')
print("about to check connection")
print("here is the connection: ", cli.is_connected())

sender = Keypair()
print(sender.secret_key)
process_airdrop = Popen(f"solana --url http://127.0.0.1:8899 airdrop 1 {sender.public_key}", shell=True)
process_airdrop.wait()

receiver = Keypair()
process_airdrop = Popen(f"solana --url http://127.0.0.1:8899 airdrop 1 {receiver.public_key}", shell=True)
process_airdrop.wait()
        
time.sleep(20)

txn = Transaction().add(transfer(TransferParams(from_pubkey=sender.public_key, to_pubkey=receiver.public_key, lamports = int(5e6))))
cli.send_transaction(txn, sender)

time.sleep(20)
print("here is the sender balanace: ", self.get_account_balance(key_value=str(sender.public_key)))
print("here is the receiver balanace: ", self.get_account_balance(key_value=str(receiver.public_key)))
```

This works, however, when I try to execute the smart contract with the `program_id` being the public key of the smart contract after the deployment of that contract with the code below:

```py
transaction = Transaction()
transaction.add(TransactionInstruction(
     [
          AccountMeta(sender.public_key, True, True),
     ],
     PublicKey(program_id),
     bytearray(0)
))

send_tx = cli.send_transaction(transaction, sender)
print("here is the transaction: ", send_tx)
```

However, I get the error:

```
Transaction simulation failed: This program may not be used for executing instructions
```

I've been reading around the subject and I'm a little overwhelmed. I'm guessing that I have to create an account for the smart contract data. Does anyone know the steps I need to get the smart contract working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to execute instructions on a program, the program data account has to be marked `executable`.

Make sure you deploy your program with `solana program deploy` in the CLI and that the deployment is successful.

You can check what is deployed at the publicKey and if it is marked as executable with [`getAccountInfo`](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getaccountinfo)

Comment: This is now working thank you! I'm now onto the next problem. It's produced a JSON keypair which I can't load into Python. The program runs but I need the account to be an owner. How do I do this? Do I create a new account that copies this? I feel like this is the last hurdle.